# Unable to send notifications via slack in Go

Tags: go, slack-api

I am trying to use the Slack API to send notifications when one of my company's Loan Specialists or Risk Analysts are assigned to a casefile.

Here is the Update function that sends Updates to a casefile to our database, which is where I call the slack notification functions I mention above.

```
func (r *Routes) UpdateCasefile(c echo.Context) error {
    var ur update.UpdateRequest

    err := c.Bind(&ur)
    if err != nil {
        return handleErr(err, "Error binding JSONUpdateRequest")
    }

    if err := ur.ToGorm(r.db, &casefile.Casefile{}).Error; err != nil {
        return handleErr(err, "Error updating Casefile")
    }

    var updated casefile.Casefile
    if err := r.db.Where("id = ?", ur.EntityID).First(&updated).Error;
    err != nil {
        return handleErr(err, "Error recalling updated Casefile")
    }

    cf := &casefile.Casefile{
        ID:                     updated.ID,
        Name:                   updated.Name,
        LoanAmount:             updated.LoanAmount,
        AssignedLoanSpecialist: updated.AssignedLoanSpecialist,
        AssignedRiskAnalyst:    updated.AssignedRiskAnalyst,
        Business:               updated.Business,
    }

    if ur.Updates["assigned_risk_analyst"] != nil {
        NotifyRiskAnalyst(cf)
    }

    if ur.Updates["assigned_loan_specialist"] != nil {
        NotifyLoanSpecialist(cf)
    }

    go func() {
        events.Bus.Events <- &events.EventMessage{
            EventType: events.EventActivity,
            Payload: &casefile.Activity{
                CasefileID: ur.EntityID,
                Type:       "UPDATE",
                User:       auth.GetEmail(c),
                Message:    ur.FormatUpdateMessage(),
             },
         }
    }()

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, updated)
}
```

Here are the functions that are *supposed* to send notifications via one of our slack channels when a Loan Specialist or Risk Analyst are assigned to a casefile.

```
func NotifyRiskAnalyst(cf *casefile.Casefile) {
    title := fmt.Sprintf("Casefile  <https://COMPANYWEBSITE/case/%s|%s>, assigned to <@%s> at %s", cf.ID, cf.Name, cf.AssignedRiskAnalyst, cf.CreatedAt.Format("2006-01-02 15:04 -0700 MST"))

    err := common.NewSlackNotifier("#test").Notify(common.SlackMessage{
        Attachments: []common.SlackAttachment{
            {
                Color:    "#008BF8",
                Fallback: title,
                Pretext:  title,
                Fields: []common.SlackField{
                    {
                        Title: cf.Name,
                        Value:   fmt.Sprintf("https:/COMPANYWEBSITE/case/%s", cf.ID),
                    },
                },
            },
        }})

    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Error("Error sending Slack message")
    }
}

func NotifyLoanSpecialist(cf *casefile.Casefile) {
    title := fmt.Sprintf("Casefile  <https://COMPANYWEBSITE/case/%s|%s>, assigned to <@%s> at %s", cf.ID, cf.Name, cf.AssignedLoanSpecialist, cf.CreatedAt.Format("2006-01-02 15:04 -0700 MST"))

    err := common.NewSlackNotifier("#test").Notify(common.SlackMessage{
        Attachments: []common.SlackAttachment{
            {
                Color:    "#008BF8",
                Fallback: title,
                Pretext:  title,
                Fields: []common.SlackField{
                    {
                        Title: cf.Name,
                        Value: fmt.Sprintf("https://COMPANYWEBSITE.io/case/%s", cf.ID),
                    },
                },
            },
        }})

    if err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Error("Error sending Slack message")
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors in my terminal, but the slack notifications aren't sending. I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong, but any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the `Notify*` functions are being called? What is the implementation of the `SlackNotifier`?

Comment: `logrus.WithError(err).Error("Error sending Slack message")` is the part of your code, that handles error logging. if its not set to stdOut, you wont see it on terminal, it might be logging that in some error log. What you can do here is to debug the code to see if `NotifyLoanSpecialist` and `NotifyRiskAnalyst` are actually being called.